# Api Localização com Zona

Tags: api, geolocalização, cep

Tenho uma base de endereços(logradouro, cidade, estado, CEP, bairro) e precisaria completar o endereço com a Zona (Leste, Norte, Sul, Oeste, Centro).

Pensei que a forma mais fácil de fazer seria por API, esse site é perfeito para ilustrar: http://thiagorodrigo.com.br/cep-sao-paulo-lista-de-cep-por-bairro-e-cidade-da-grande-sao-paulo/, mas não achei API, alguém conhece alguma?

PS.: Se for só São Paulo já atende a maioria dos meus endereços.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exportei id e CEP de toda minha base de dados para um Excel, peguei as faixas de CEP por zona nesse site: http://rainydays.com.br/faixas-de-cep-de-sao-paulo e coloquei no mesmo Excel. Separando pelas colunas Zona, Inicio e Fim

Fiz um PROCV procurando os CEPs da minha base na Tabela de faixa de CEP me retornando a Zona. Agora eu tinha id e Zona, com isso montei um UPDATE e executei no Banco de Dados.